# signalr creates new connection id using the same browser on same page refresh by default in c#

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client, sqldependency

by default signalr hub starts on each page load and creates new connection id on same browser on same page refresh or new tab in c#.

i am sorry its not signalr problem, but in my situation, but how i need signalr updates.

signalr creates new connection id on each page refresh and hold the previous connection id's.when any update receive, it sends updates to each new connection

but i want 1 connection for one browser each tabs, it should not create new connection id for the same browser on refresh or on new tab.

code i used:

1. `JobHub.cs` class

   ```
   public class JobHub : Hub
    {
       public static void Show()
          {
           IHubContext context =   GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<JobHub>();
           context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
          }
     }
   ```
2. `View.cshtml`

   ```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var job = $.connection.jobHub;
    job.client.displayStatus = function () {
               alert("change notice");
               getData();
           };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
               //connection started
               alert("connection started");
               getData();
           });

    function getData() {
           var $tbl = $('#tblJobInfo');
           $.ajax({
               url: 'http://localhost:51737/api/values',
               type: 'GET',
               datatype: 'json',
               success: function (data) {
                   if (data.length > 0) {
                       $tbl.empty();
                       $tbl.append(' <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Last Executed Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>');
                       var rows = [];
                       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                           rows.push(' <tr><td>' + data[i].JobID + '</td><td>' + data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data[i].LastExecutionDate.toString().substr(0,10) + '</td><td>' + data[i].Status + '</td></tr>');
                       }
                       $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                   }
               }
           });
       }
   ```
3. `Div`

   ```
    <div>
    <table id="tblJobInfo" style="text-align:center;margin-left:10px"> </table></div>
   ```
4. `JobInfo.cs` and `JobInfoRepository.cs`

   ```
   public class JobInfo
   {
       public int JobID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime LastExecutionDate { get; set; }
       public string Status { get; set; }
   }
   public class JobInfoRepository
   {

       public IEnumerable<JobInfo> GetData()
       {

           using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
           {
               connection.Open();
               using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [JobID],[Name],[LastExecutionDate],[Status]
              FROM [dbo].[JobInfo]", connection))
               {
                   // Make sure the command object does not already have
                   // a notification object associated with it.
                   command.Notification = null;

                   SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                   dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                   if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                       connection.Open();

                   using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                       return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                           .Select(x => new JobInfo()
                           {
                               JobID = x.GetInt32(0),
                               Name = x.GetString(1),
                               LastExecutionDate = x.GetDateTime(2),
                               Status = x.GetString(3)
                           }).ToList();



               }
           }
       }
       private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
       {

           //calling hub notification
           JobHub.Show();

       }
   }
   ```
5. API `ValuesController.cs`

   ```
   public class ValuesController : ApiController
   {
    JobInfoRepository objRepo = new JobInfoRepository();

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<JobInfo> Get()
    {
       return objRepo.GetData();
    }
   }
   ```

   after refreshing the page whenever i get updates by DB, it call sql dependency change event multiple times.
   please guide or help me, how can i handle this situation. i appreciate your valuable time and effort.